# How get most product added to favorites list in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have `favourites` table like this:

```
id -user_id - product_id
```

It's for user to add the favourites product, and I have my relation in `User Model:`

```
public function favourites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class ,'favourites')->withTimestamps();
}
```

How can I fetch the most product added to favorites by users! ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count(*)` with `group by`.

```php
Favorite::selectRaw('product_id, count(product_id) as times_added')
->groupBy('product_id')
->orderByDesc('times_added')
// ->limit(5) if you want to get the top 5
->get();
```

If you don't have a model for your `favorites` table you can use the `DB` facade.

```php
DB::table('favorites')
->selectRaw('product_id, count(product_id) as times_added')
->groupBy('product_id')
->orderByDesc('times_added')
// ->limit(5) if you want to get the top 5
->get();
```

Comment: Can I get the data of product directly like I need the name of product!